# Error TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django

After trying to fix this and looking at every solution I could find for hours, I couldn't fix this problem.

I am using Django version 1.11.2.

Here is my settings.py:
`

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'climateChange.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'climateChange.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`
Here is my project setup:
[project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WR5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

As your `templates` is in project base directory, change your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+'/templates/'],  #<<<<<<<<templates dir
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, not correct but it led me to the answer. In my views I had  'return render(request, 'home/home.html')'. But strangely enough(at least strange to me), it was supposed to be, 'return render(request, 'home.html')'.

Comment: It is correct, your `home.html` is in the template folder, you have to tell your `views` to find the template folder first, that's why you have to put correct path to `DIRS`. unless you have templates folder in `home` directory, then you can keep `DIRS` is empty, directly `return render(request, 'home/home.html')`, it will go to your apps root folder (home), not project folder, then find `templates/home/home.html`

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory in your project's root directory name "templates". Move your all html files to that templates directory.

Now, In settings.py,

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASR_DIR, 'templates'],  ## Here we have set that templates directory as your default templates directory
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And, In your functions, replace your path of html files like,

```
'templates/home.html'
```

OR simply,

```
'home.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [MEDIA_ROOT + '/'],# Here i mention media root so your wish you can own dirs
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

seems your settings.py template directory is empty.so Create a directory in your project's root directory name and you can define what i gave comment